# Angular filter ng-repeat into seperate lists

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object I have flattened to retrieve specific items (only) out of that I am running through a repeat. I am wondering if I could have the repeat spit out the items in small groupings.

Each item has a category key and I just want them to be put in the html grouped by like category.

I could do something like this -

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myObject | category1">{{name}}</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in myObject | category2">{{name}}</div> 
<div ng-repeat="item in myObject | category3">{{name}}</div>
```

However there are 15 or so categories and about 80-100 items in the object, so I am wondering if there is some kind of way to write a few lines and have angular handle the distribution instead of "hardcoding" each category. Also - the categories might change later and it would be great if a developer didn't have to come in and change the hardcoded categories.

For reference, the object just looks like this -

```
  $scope.myObject = [{'name' : item1' , 'category' : 'category1'},{'name' : item2' , 'category' : 'category2'}];
```

My first guess is to run the object through some kind of filtering that spits out an array of the categories to repeat, then inside that repeat, filter the original object by that current item in the repeat -

```
  //categories is myObject filtered down to an array of categories (1 of each)
  <div ng-repeat="category in categories">
       <div ng-repeat="item in myObject | category">
             {{item.name}}
       </div>
 </div>
```

I'm wondering if there is a better or more elegant way of dealing with this? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really easy if you use a library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy):

In your controller:

```
$scope.myObjGrouped= _.groupBy($scope.myObject, 'category');
```

In your HTML:

```
  <div ng-repeat="(category, objects) in myObjGrouped">
       <div ng-repeat="item in objects">
             {{item.name}}
       </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is great thank you! is there a way to display the name of the category above the item in objects repeat - something like {{myObjGrouped[$index]}}

Comment: nvm got it, its just {{category}} right below the first repeat. Thank you !!